# Graphics (geeqie) slow after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, 15.04, intel-graphics

I upgraded an IBM Thinkpad T440p from 14.10 to 15.04 the other day. I am noticing that full-screen image viewing is *really* slow. For `geeqie` to paint the screen (of a 1920x1080 external monitor) with a digital camera image used to be (i.e., in 14.10 and previously) essentially instantaneous, but now it takes it several seconds, and the incremental screen updates left to right and top to bottom are visible, chunk by chunk. It's like some X server option is not set properly, but I have no idea what it could be.

I'm running xfce4 (now and before the update, for a very long time). The application I generally use for image viewing is `geeqie`, as stated above. Other than image viewing, things don't seem bad; I don't think I've tried local video via `vlc` or `xine` but browser-based video seems to work fine.

*edit* — just found this possibly related issue about Gnome problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721

lspci info:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T440p
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900       60.0 +
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Unfortunately I'm not on my external monitor now, but here's an xdpyinfo anyway:

```
name of display:    :0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11701000
X.Org version: 1.17.1
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  window 0x2000004, revert to Parent
number of extensions:    28
    BIG-REQUESTS
    Composite
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    DPMS
    DRI2
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    Present
    RANDR
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SGI-GLX
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XFree86-DGA
    XFree86-VidModeExtension
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    1600x900 pixels (420x236 millimeters)
  resolution:    97x97 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0xaf
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x22
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store WHEN MAPPED, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    256x256
  current input event mask:    0xfa800f
    KeyPressMask             KeyReleaseMask           ButtonPressMask          
    ButtonReleaseMask        ExposureMask             StructureNotifyMask      
    SubstructureNotifyMask   SubstructureRedirectMask FocusChangeMask          
    PropertyChangeMask       ColormapChangeMask       
  number of visuals:    20
  default visual id:  0x20
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 oh right, sorry; I knew I forgot something.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what happens when I forget to install my hardware acceleration drivers. Usually fglrx for ATI or nouveau for nvidia.

Comment: I agree, but in this case it's a laptop with Intel graphics, and it's already using the up-to-date Intel drivers. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, sorry I couldn't help, it was worth a shot thought.